# Why do I have different KS test results?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have been using scipython ks2samp to apply a two sided , sample KS test to some data.

import scipy.stats as ss

import numpy as np

All_smirnoff = ss.ks_2samp(X, Y)

where X and Y are two 1D numpy arrays len(32) and len(25).

This works fine and the output I get for this is:

n1= 32 n2= 25
All smirnoff is Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.3625, pvalue=0.0370518090003172)

Where the statistic is Dmax.

I have 2 questions:

Q1 if I use an old fashion look up table approach to calculate a Dcrit for P = 0.05

Dcrit,0.05 = 1.36*sqrt(1/n1 * 1/n2)

e.g. [http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~massa/Lecture%2013.pdf](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Emassa/Lecture%2013.pdf)

I get this result

smirnoff crit is at p 0.05 0.3630206605690646
n1= 32 n2= 25

Which is very close to the Dmax value that scipy thinks is p = 0.037. This seems like quite a big discrepancy to me in terms of P values?

In another example the D value given by scipy had a pvalue of 0.04 but according to the approximation above p > 0.05.

Should I be concerned or is it just that the look up table approach is quite a lot less accurate? Can different approaches to applying the test result in this sort of discrepancy? Or have I just done something wrong here?

Q2

The samples in my populations are not truly independent, therefore this affects my test result. Unfortunately there is no way to really get around this. I have tried to implement the test but using less assumed degrees of freedom so a smaller 'n' number in the calculation of p, to see how this affects my result. Is there a way to do this in scipy?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: The formula you quote, `Dcrit,0.05 = 1.36*sqrt(1/n1 * 1/n2)`, is explicitly an *approximation.*

Comment: I So the answer to my question is yes then? I can expect this decrepency. Thanks